# Node modules size?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I really can't understand what really happens when i run this command in my terminal `npm install`, after few seconds i find  node_modules folder with a size of at least 150MB or far bigger sometimes.

This is too much for my network capacity, When i download a movie for example, this doesn't happen in that speed, so i need to understand what is really happening when i run this command.

Do i really download a  150MB or more files size, or npm just download small files and do some work that makes it that big!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've run `npm install` previously (even in another folder/directory), subsequent `npm install` runs can get some/many/all packages from a local cache. From https://docs.npmjs.com/cli-commands/cache.html:

> npm stores cache data in an opaque directory within the configured cache, named _cacache. This directory is a cacache-based content-addressable cache that stores all http request data as well as other package-related data. This directory is primarily accessed through pacote, the library responsible for all package fetching as of npm@5.

If you want to force `npm` to go over the network so you can compare performance, remove your `node_modules` directory, run `npm cache clear`, and then do `npm install`.

Comment: so npm woud install all packages from the cache unless face a package that not exist in the cach or not installed before??

Comment: Assuming your package.json provides minimum versions of dependencies rather than pinning to a specific version, I would imagine npm would query the repository to get the latest version that would be used, and then it would check the cache for that version and only download from the registry if it's not already in the cache. It might also use any cached version that meets requirements, even if it's not the latest, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, it downloads all that data fully, no post-processing. It does however link the dependencies, so the final size might be a bit larger.

Comment: But how, i live in a country with relatively slow internet, i can't download a file with a size of 300MB in less than 5 mins, with npm i can download the same size in a minute or two , this is confusing!

Comment: @CodeEagle you must also take in consideration that the latency of the servers where you are downloading movies from might be slower.

Comment: @PedroLourenço, it is just an example, i am talking about downloading a movie with my full download speed which is far much slower than npm as i notice